# Print part of an array or a file and sort in shell

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a text file as follows

```
     1 : dis conn(*) type(CONN) all where(UOWLOG ne '')
AMQ8276: Display Connection details.
   CONN(AE1CA9572C47D822)                
   EXTCONN(414D51434D5147575032202020202020)
   TYPE(CONN)                            
   PID(9098)                               TID(503215) 
   APPLDESC(WebSphere MQ Channel)       
   APPLTAG(WebSphere MQ Client for Java)
   APPLTYPE(USER)                          ASTATE(NONE)
   CHANNEL(ABIS.CLIENT)           CLIENTID( )
   CONNAME(101.54.151.80)               
   CONNOPTS(MQCNO_HANDLE_SHARE_BLOCK,MQCNO_FASTPATH_BINDING)
   USERID(malth)                         UOWLOG(S0599315.LOG)
   UOWSTDA(2016-08-16)                     UOWSTTI(11.06.38)
   UOWLOGDA(2016-08-16)                    UOWLOGTI(11.06.38)
   URTYPE(QMGR)                         
   EXTURID(XA_FORMATID[] XA_GTRID[] XA_BQUAL[])
   QMURID(0.190537069)                     UOWSTATE(ACTIVE)
AMQ8276: Display Connection details.
   CONN(AE1CA957D787F429)                
   EXTCONN(414D51434D5147575032202020202020)
   TYPE(CONN)                            
   PID(28292)                              TID(1519092) 
   APPLDESC(WebSphere MQ Channel)       
   APPLTAG(WebSphere MQ Client for Java)
   APPLTYPE(USER)                          ASTATE(NONE)
   CHANNEL(SB.CLIENT)                  CLIENTID( )
   CONNAME(101.54.151.119)              
   CONNOPTS(MQCNO_HANDLE_SHARE_BLOCK,MQCNO_FASTPATH_BINDING)
   USERID(sbp)                         UOWLOG(S0599317.LOG)
   UOWSTDA(2016-08-16)                     UOWSTTI(11.07.38)
   UOWLOGDA(2016-08-16)                    UOWLOGTI(11.07.38)
   URTYPE(QMGR)                         
   EXTURID(XA_FORMATID[] XA_GTRID[] XA_BQUAL[])
   QMURID(0.190520281)                     UOWSTATE(ACTIVE)
AMQ8276: Display Connection details.
   CONN(2CC7AE57CE8E6221)                
   EXTCONN(414D51434D5147575032202020202020)
   TYPE(CONN)                            
   PID(22400)                              TID(647335) 
   APPLDESC(WebSphere MQ Channel)       
   APPLTAG(WebSphere MQ Client for Java)
   APPLTYPE(USER)                          ASTATE(NONE)
   CHANNEL(U90785.CBM.CLIENT)              CLIENTID( )
   CONNAME(101.54.163.37)               
   CONNOPTS(MQCNO_HANDLE_SHARE_BLOCK,MQCNO_FASTPATH_BINDING)
   USERID(machlth)                         UOWLOG(S0599317.LOG)
   UOWSTDA(2016-08-16)                     UOWSTTI(11.07.40)
   UOWLOGDA(2016-08-16)                    UOWLOGTI(11.07.40)
   URTYPE(QMGR)                         
   EXTURID(XA_FORMATID[] XA_GTRID[] XA_BQUAL[])
   QMURID(0.190574800)                     UOWSTATE(ACTIVE)
AMQ8276: Display Connection details.
   CONN(2CC7AE571BF0B721)                
   EXTCONN(414D51434D5147575032202020202020)
   TYPE(CONN)                            
   PID(22210)                              TID(1069968) 
   APPLDESC(WebSphere MQ Channel)       
   APPLTAG(WebSphere MQ Client for Java)
   APPLTYPE(USER)                          ASTATE(NONE)
   CHANNEL(APP.CLIENT)                  CLIENTID( )
   CONNAME(101.54.163.127)              
   CONNOPTS(MQCNO_HANDLE_SHARE_BLOCK,MQCNO_FASTPATH_BINDING)
   USERID(apsp)                            UOWLOG(S0599317.LOG)
   UOWSTDA(2016-08-16)                     UOWSTTI(11.07.29)
   UOWLOGDA(2016-08-16)                    UOWLOGTI(11.07.29)
   URTYPE(QMGR)                         
   EXTURID(XA_FORMATID[] XA_GTRID[] XA_BQUAL[])
```

Now i want my output to to show

```
ABIS.CLIENT,101.54.151.80,malth,S0599315.LOG,11.06.38
APP.CLIENT,101.54.163.127,apsp,S0599317.LOG,11.07.29
SB.CLIENT,101.54.151.119,sbp,S0599317.LOG,11.07.38
CBM.CLIENT,101.54.163.37,machlth,S0599317.LOG,11.07.40
```

so basically, get the channel name, conname, userid,UUOWLOG and UOWLOGTI and sort it all in the end by UOWLOGTI. 
I am trying to do this in shell.

I have tried using `awk` but can't seem to get the desired output.

`cat UOWLOG.txt|awk -vRS="" 'BEGIN{printf ""}/\<'AMQ8276'\>/^CHANNEL{printf $0 RT}'`
I get errors when i try different options in awk. 
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all can be done in `awk` but perhaps easier with a chain of tools

```
$ grep -oP '(CHANNEL|CONNAME|USERID|UOWLOG|UOWLOGTI)\(.*?\)' file | 
  awk -F'[()]' '{ORS=NR%5?",":RS; print $2}' | 
  sort -t, -k5

ABIS.CLIENT,101.54.151.80,malth,S0599315.LOG,11.06.38
APP.CLIENT,101.54.163.127,apsp,S0599317.LOG,11.07.29
SB.CLIENT,101.54.151.119,sbp,S0599317.LOG,11.07.38
U90785.CBM.CLIENT,101.54.163.37,machlth,S0599317.LOG,11.07.40
```

Comment: this works. I tried inserting an if statement to check if UOWLOTI is less than a threshold say 11.07.00 only then print the output. `grep -oP '(CHANNEL|CONNAME|USERID|UOWLOG|UOWLOGTI)\(.*?\)' file|awk -F'[()]' '{if($5 ge 11.07.00)ORS=NR%5?",":RS; print $2}' | sort -t, -k5` . Is that wrong

Comment: there are only two fields at that point.  Also, should be `>=`.  I would instead do it as a post process.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is similar to @karakfa's but makes no assumptions for fields order:

```
$ grep -o '^\w\+:\|\w\+[(][^)]\+[)]' file |
  awk -F '[()]' -v OFS="," 'function printValues() { if ("CHANNEL" in p) { print p["CHANNEL"], p["CONNAME"], p["USERID"], p["UOWLOG"], p["UOWLOGTI"] } } /^\w+:/ { printValues(); delete p; next } { p[$1] = $2 } END { printValues() }' |
  sort -t, -k 5
```

What I'm doing is creating an associative array for each "record" and then only printing the fields necessary.

Answer (score 1):

My lil bit dirty  `gnu awk` solution:

```
$ awk -v RS="AMQ" 'NR>1{
print gensub(/.*CHANNEL\(([^)]+).*CONNAME\(([^)]+).*USERID\(([^)]+).*UOWLOG\(([^)]+).*UOWLOGTI\(([^)]+).*/,"\\1,\\2,\\3,\\4,\\5","1")}' file | sort -t "," -k5
ABIS.CLIENT,101.54.151.80,malth,S0599315.LOG,11.06.38
APP.CLIENT,101.54.163.127,apsp,S0599317.LOG,11.07.29
SB.CLIENT,101.54.151.119,sbp,S0599317.LOG,11.07.38
U90785.CBM.CLIENT,101.54.163.37,machlth,S0599317.LOG,11.07.40
```

Answer (score 1):

I dunno, but the accepted answer doesn't produce the specified output for the "CBM.CLIENT" channel, and all the answers so far are intense one-liners.  When the transformation is this complex, I like whole script, so I can see what's what.

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f 

function Print() {
    OFS = ","
    print line["CHANNEL"], line["CONNAME"], line["USERID"],     \
          line["UOWLOG"], line["UOWLOGTI"]
    delete line
}

/Display Connection details[.]$/ {
    if( length(line) ) {
        Print()
    }
    next
}

$1 == "CHANNEL" {
    line[$1] = $2
    if( 3 == split( $2, channel, /[.]/ ) ) {
        line[$1] = channel[2] "." channel[3]
    }
    next
}

{
    line[$1] = $2
}

END { Print() }
```

The technique is to build an associative array of all the *foo(bar)* elements, and print the interesting bits in an obvious way.  The regexes are simple and input assumptions are relaxed: no field-order dependency, and very little formatting dependency.

It relies on a little pre-processing to put each key/value pair on its own line, and post-processing to sort the output.  Invoke as:

```
$ cat f.sh
#! /bin/sh
sed -E 's/^ +//; s/ +$//g; s/  +/\
/g'  $1 | awk -F '[:()]' -f script.awk | sort -t, -k5

$ ./f.sh dat
ABIS.CLIENT,101.54.151.80,malth,S0599315.LOG,11.06.38
APP.CLIENT,101.54.163.127,apsp,S0599317.LOG,11.07.29
SB.CLIENT,101.54.151.119,sbp,S0599317.LOG,11.07.38
CBM.CLIENT,101.54.163.37,machlth,S0599317.LOG,11.07.40
```

In the comments, the OP mentions printing only lines that meet a certain criterion.  That's easy to add to this `Print()` function, and easy to understand later, too.