# How to identify list of queues and queue names in cluster in IBM MQ and add / remove queues in cluster?

Tags: ibm-mq

I need to identify the clustered queues in the queue manager. I need the output as queue name and clustername.

Add queues to cluster which queues are not in cluster
remove queues from cluster which queues are in cluster

Comment: Removed the [tag:linux] and [tag:ibm].  Linux is for questions related to programming using Linux APIs or Linux-specific behavior.  IBM is for general question related to the company IBM, not specific products from IBM.

Comment: Do you want to output only queues that exist on the local queue manager that are clustered, or do you want to see clustered queues that may not be local that the local queue manager has knowledge of?

Comment: I want to output only queues that exist on the local queue manager that are clustered

Comment: When i execute this line 

**echo "DISPLAY Q(*) WHERE(CLUSNL EQ '')")|runmqsc <qmgr> | grep "QUEUE(" | awk -F'[()]' '{print $2}' | sort | uniq -c | awk '{ if ($1 ~ /2/) {print $2}}'**

I got an error 
**awk: cmd. line:1: {if ($1 ~ /2/){{print $2}}
awk: cmd. line:1:   ^ unexpected newline or end of string**

I corrected it
It displays empty

Comment: I added a new section that will output a csv format with "QUEUENAME,CLUSTER,CLUSNL".  Please let me know if this does not address your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display all queues which have the `CLUSTER` or `CLUSNL` attribute set on the local queue manager you can use the `WHERE` parameter to search for queues with a `CLUSTER` or `CLUSNL` attribute that is `NE` (NOT EQUAL) to `''` (blank).

`printf "DISPLAY Q(*) WHERE(CLUSTER NE '')\nDISPLAY Q(*) WHERE(CLUSNL NE '')" | runmqsc <qmgr> | grep "QUEUE(" | awk -F'[()]' '{print $2}'`

---

The variation of below will print a CSV output with "QUEUE,CLUSTER,CLUSNL".  The printValues syntax is from @mike.dld answer to this post "[Print part of an array or a file and sort in shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38980757/print-part-of-an-array-or-a-file-and-sort-in-shell/38981789#38981789)"

`printf "DISPLAY Q(*) WHERE(CLUSTER NE '')\nDISPLAY Q(*) WHERE(CLUSNL NE '')" | runmqsc <qmgr> | grep -o '^\w\+:\|\w\+[(][^)]\+[)]' | awk -F '[()]' -v OFS="," 'function printValues() { if ("QUEUE" in p) { print p["QUEUE"], p["CLUSTER"], p["CLUSNL"] } } /^\w+:/ { printValues(); delete p; next } { p[$1] = $2 } END { printValues() }'`

---

To display all queues which do not have the `CLUSTER` and `CLUSNL` attribute set on the local queue manager you can use the `WHERE` parameter to search for queues with a `CLUSTER` and `CLUSNL` attribute that is `EQ` (EQUAL) to `''` (blank).  sort, uniq, and awk help show only those where both are blank.

`printf "DISPLAY Q(*) WHERE(CLUSTER EQ '')\nDISPLAY Q(*) WHERE(CLUSNL EQ '')" | runmqsc <qmgr> | grep "QUEUE(" | awk -F'[()]' '{print $2}' | sort | uniq -c | awk '{ if ($1 ~ /2/) {print $2}}'`

---

To add a queue to a cluster you need to `ALTER` it to set the `CLUSTER` attribute to the name of a valid cluster.  You can also use the `CLUSNL` attribute to specify a `NAMELIST`, the `NAMELIST` must contain at least one cluster name but can contain more than one cluster name allowing the queue to be in multiple clusters.

`echo "ALTER QL(TEST.Q) CLUSTER(RAJCLUS)" | runmqsc <qmgr>`

---

To remove a queue from the cluster you need to blank out the `CLUSTER` and `CLUSNL` attributes.

`echo "ALTER QL(TEST.Q) CLUSTER('') CLUSNL('')" | runmqsc <qmgr>`

Comment: **1 : DIS QL(*) WHERE(CLUSTER EQ '')
AMQ8409: Display Queue details.
   QUEUE(Q2.APPLE)                         TYPE(QLOCAL)
   CLUSTER( )                           
AMQ8409: Display Queue details.
   QUEUE(Q3.APPLE)                         TYPE(QLOCAL)
   CLUSTER( )**  

Above result are the queue which are not in cluster..
How can i extract only a queue name from this output?? it is possible

Comment: yep.. I want to just see Q3.APPLE as output

Comment: @JoshMc - `CLUSNL` ?

Comment: @T.Rob Good point.  Updated to check for either.  Also added a check for queues that are not clustered.

Comment: I got an error in **awk '{if ($1 ~ /2/){{print $2}}'**

error is awk: cmd. line:1: {if ($1 ~ /2/){{print $2}}
awk: cmd. line:1:   ^ unexpected newline or end of string

Comment: **printf "DISPLAY Q(*) WHERE(CLUSTER NE '')\nDISPLAY Q(*) WHERE(CLUSNL NE '')" | runmqsc <qmgr> | grep -o '^\w\+:\|\w\+[(][^)]\+[)]' | awk -F '[()]' -v OFS="," 'function printValues() { if ("QUEUE" in p) { print p["QUEUE"], p["CLUSTER"], p["CLUSNL"] } } /^\w+:/ { printValues(); delete p; next } { p[$1] = $2 } END { printValues() }'** 

This code works fine @JoshMc

Comment: Thank you sooo much @JoshMc.. You saved a time for me.. You great Man..!!